# How can I complete these four vectors to eight orthogonal vectors in $\Bbb R^8$?

Tags: orthogonality

Not sure on the exact terminology to use in the question title, easier to explain with code.

I want to come up with 8 orthogonal vectors in R^8 space. I know what the first 4 vectors should be, I don't particularly care what the last 4 should be, as long as they are all mutually orthogonal.

This is how I am defining the first 4 in R

```
factor1 = rep(1, 8)
factor2 = c(rep(1,4), rep(-1,4))
factor3 = rep(c(rep(1,2), rep(-1,2)), 2)
factor4 = rep(c(1,-1), 4)
factors = cbind(factor1, factor2, factor3, factor4)
```

this is what results

```
     factor1 factor2 factor3 factor4
[1,]       1       1       1       1
[2,]       1       1       1      -1
[3,]       1       1      -1       1
[4,]       1       1      -1      -1
[5,]       1      -1       1       1
[6,]       1      -1       1      -1
[7,]       1      -1      -1       1
[8,]       1      -1      -1      -1
```

and I know they are orthogonal: `round(t(factors) %*% factors, 10)` gives

```
        factor1 factor2 factor3 factor4
factor1       8       0       0       0
factor2       0       8       0       0
factor3       0       0       8       0
factor4       0       0       0       8
```

There is a simple pattern I am using to generate first 4, is there a way to continue this pattern to generate the next 4? If there is no one/simple pattern, any will do as long as the result is orthogonal.

Comment: Extend your independent set to a basis in any way you desire, then apply the Gram-Schmidt process to produce an orthogonal basis.

Comment: @JBL, not too familiar with that, but wouldn't that alter the first 4 vectors in the process?

Comment: No, because they are already orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can complete with
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\-1\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\1\\-1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\-1\\-1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\-1\\0\\0\\-1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: This gives me the answer I was looking for, so acceepted. I wonder though, is it impossible to do with only -1 and 1 elemensts?

Comment: Unless I made a (hand-)computing mistake, it is impossible: I found that the only four vectors with only $-1$ and $1$ elements and orthogonal to your first four vectors are (up to sign) $(1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1),$ $(1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1),$ and $(1,-1,x,-x,-1,1,-x,x)$ with $x=\pm1,$ but these last two are not orthogonal to eachother.